# Using Node SOAP to connect to web service

Tags: node.js, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I'm trying to use Node Soap to connect to a SOAP web service (https://test.8f7.com/4DWSDl.html) . Using the WSDL url on Soapclient's SOAP test ([soapclient.com/soaptest.html](http://soapclient.com/soaptest.html)) works as intended. When using it in the library, I keep getting an error "Invalid WSDL URL: Code 406". I've tried removing the .html from the URL (which exposes the XML) but I keep getting the same result. I have included my code snippet below. Any recommendations?

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'https://test.8f7.com/4DWSDL.html';

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
  if(err) console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Did you look up what code 406 is?

Comment: Looks like it's a Non-Acceptable Error. The node-soap library doesn't look like it restricts XML responses.